# Vite app HMR and mounting volume in docker container on a azure VM doesn't work

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, vuejs3, vite

Now I have tried both googling and testing all possible solutions without success. I want to mount the frontend app so that hmr works. If I run locally with docker desktop, everything works as it should, but as soon as I change the context to the docker environment on my VM and try to mount the volume, I get an error.

Can someone please explain to me how to make it work?

I want to be able to develop the frontend in the right environment and still have hmr active so I can see all changes immediately and not have to rebuild the container as soon as I make a change.

### This i folder structure:

```
/Application
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
/api
  Dockerfile
/app (vite root)
  /node_modules
  /public
  /src
  Dockerfile
  .env
  vite.config.js
  etc.
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  network:
    name: ssl_network

services:
  frontend:
    image: my-frontend
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    networks:
      - network
```

### Dockerfile inside app folder

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
USER root
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm i --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

### Error

when trying to run docker compose up --build -d when volumes: is present i compose file..

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-10T21_50_41_655Z-debug-0.log
```

If I skip mounting the volume it works, I don't get a warning but hmr doesn't work either..
so it is not an option.

I hope someone has a good answer. I have redone the dockerfile that is in the app folder 200 times soon and also changed back and forth in the compose file but nothing seems to work..